# Typescript misinterprets the interface of an imported JSON file. How do you fix it?

Tags: typescript

The JSON file I have has a structure which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "keys": [
      {
        "date": "2019-06-25T17:33:39.000Z"
      }
    ],
    "tag": null
  },
  {
    "keys": [],
    "tag": "stringvalue"
  }
]
```

Because the second `keys` is an empty array, after importing the file, Typescript assumes `keys` can be of `any[]` type (therefore, making `keys` be of type `any[] | IKeys[]`, where `IKeys` is the true shape interface of `keys`). This prohibits the use of methods like `Array.map()` because the call signature is incompatible.

How do you fix this so that Typescript understands the true interface of `keys`?

Here is a sandbox example. https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-kare-g7r5r

Comment: Please consider editing this code to constitute a [mcve].  As it stands [I can't reproduce your issue](https://repl.it/@jcalz/56760152).  You'll get much better responses if you make it as easy as possible for others to see what you're seeing.  good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Good point.  I added a sandbox and changed the example in post to the exact JSON code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to get Typescript to figure it out on its own, but you can always cast it yourself like:

```
const keys = file.keys as { date: string}[]
```